# Name for pattern of addressing items by sequence-of-creation

Tags: distributed-systems

I'm looking for the name of a particular pattern, and/or resources (articles) on its usage.

The context of the pattern is a journalling system to operate on some collection, as in the example given here:

We could model an webstore using patterns from event-sourcing. In such a model, we would have a collection (e.g. a set) of products. Manipulation of the set would be modeled as a stream of events; typical events to manipulate the set could be "add" "remove" and "change".

All manipulation happens using the events; the resulting collection is constructed simply by replaying the events.

Given the linear nature of the stream of events, we can address each of the items in the set a using unique natural number, being the number of items that were added before it.

I.e. the first added item would be numbered 0, the second added item 1 etc.

Deletion does not affect the amount of added items, so it does not affect the next-used number. Of course, it does lead to "gaps" in the sequence. If we were to start with an empty set, add an item and then delete it, the index 0 points to no (currently existing) item, and the next item to be added will be addressed using 1.

Such an addressing scheme could be useful in a distributed context, where a shared view exists for the history up to a certain point, but the histories diverge from that point onwards. Using the addressing scheme, the various parts of the distributed 
mechanism can unambiguously refer to elements from the set.

Is this a well known pattern in the literature?

Comment: Are you asking about CRDTs?

Comment: This sounds similar to how the update sequence works in CouchDB.  Although the sequence increases on all DB operations instead of just the adds.

Comment: @GManNickG nope; although I can imagine the pattern described above has a name that is described in some textbook on CRDTs